# Why is Xcode 15 giving me deprecated code errors?

Tags: xcode, unreal-engine5, xcode15

My build (of an Unreal Engine project) worked fine in Xcode 14, but in 15 I get errors like these:

`/Users/zeev/dev/UnrealEngine3/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/IsTriviallyCopyConstructible.h:13:17: builtin __has_trivial_copy is deprecated; use __is_trivially_copyable instead [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-builtins]`

`/Users/zeev/dev/UnrealEngine3/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/IsTriviallyDestructible.h:18:18: builtin __has_trivial_destructor is deprecated; use __is_trivially_destructible instead [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-builtins]`

`/Users/zeev/dev/UnrealEngine3/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/IsTriviallyCopyAssignable.h:13:17: builtin __has_trivial_assign is deprecated; use __is_trivially_assignable instead [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-builtins]`

Do I have to edit these hundreds of lines of code, or can I use an older compiler, or is there some other solution?

Comment: Yes, this is deprecated. In our own code, we would generally fix it ourselves. If there were many changes, rather than doing them one by one, we might do a global replace (or sometimes we can have Xcode fix all of them in one fell swoop, though that isn’t an option if Xcode isn’t offering a default “fix” for the error).

Comment: But you’re talking about a third-party library and you wouldn't generally go in and make changes to their source. I’m gathering that this isn't the latest engine, so if getting a more recent version will probably solve this problem. Alternatively, if you’re stuck with this version, you might turn off one of those two build settings, either `-Wdeprecated_builtins` (asking the compiler to warn you about deprecated builtins) or `-Werror` (asking the compiler to treat all warnings as errors).